# How do I auto compute Header and Row UDF values in SAP B1

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

We have an addon that processes the Sales Order and creates a Delivery from it. I plan to have a UDF U_Inner_Volume on both the ODLN and DLN1 tables. They should auto compute when the Delivery is created.

The DLN1.U_Inner_Volume will have the formula below:

```
DLN1.Volume * 0.75
```

The ODLN.U_Inner_Volume will have the formula below:

```
SUM(DLN1.U_Inner_Volume)
```

The database is MS-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your addon you could listen to the *FORM_DATA_ADD* events. Since the event may be raised after adding data within any B1 form, check the event's form UID or form type. You are looking specifically for the sales order form.
Afterwards you can read the DLN1 values and calculate and update the UDF.

Another (more database-focused) option is to use the stored procedure *SBO_SP_TransactionNotification*. It is automatically called after each transaction. Here, you could check for the transaction type of ADD and the object type for a sales order.

Comment: The SBO_SP_TransactionNotification looks more promising. I'll give it a try. Much appreciated and much obliged :-)